# Magento 2 : template file not overridden correctly

Tags: magento2

I have wrote the below code to override magento 2 frontend customer edit form.

customer_account_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_Modul::customer/form/edit.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it is not working. Please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Emipro_Module::customer/form/edit.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have used above code and its work fine for me. 
Also Your code seems right. Did you make your phtml file under proper location like: Vendor/Module_Name/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml

Also check that if there is no any spell mistake in your module name or path.

Answer (score 0):

> customer_account_edit.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_Module::customer/form/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> you need to create a template file for this on the Path.
>    app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml